# Создать массив структур со студентами на Си

Tags: c, массивы, структуры, struct

При создании функции, которая добавляет студентов в массив структур, подсвечивает красным.
 Вот весь код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>


struct addStudent(char name[], unsigned int age, unsigned int course, unsigned int);

struct student {
    char name[50];
    unsigned int age;
    unsigned int course;
};

unsigned int student_counter = 0;

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    struct student st[20];

    strcpy_s(st[0].name, 50, "Руслан");
    st[0].age = 18;
    st[0].course = 1;
    student_counter += 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < student_counter; i++) {
        printf("%s \t %d курс \t  %d лет \n", st[i].name, st[i].course, st[i].age);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

struct addStudent(char name[], unsigned age, unsigned course, unsigned age){
    student res_st;
    scrcpy_s(res_st, 50, name);



}
```

Почему не получается создать функцию addStudent? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что вы хотели написать этой строкой? `struct addStudent(char name[], unsigned int age, unsigned int course, unsigned int);`? Если это функция, то что она возвращает?

Comment: Я хотел написать функцию, которая принимает имя, возраст и курс, и возвращает структуру, которая потом сохранится в массив.

Comment: **Какую** структуру? Структуру *вообще*?

Comment: Эту функцию я взял нашел на одном сайте ```student addStudent (char ch[], unsigned int cr, unsigned int ag)
{
  student res_st;
  strcpy(res_st.nm, ch);
  res_st.course = cr;
  res_st.age = ag;
  student_counter++;
  return res_st;
}```

Comment: А теперь сравните с тем, что написали вы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам стоило бы изучить указатели и выделение памяти

вот рабочий пример:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct student *addStudent(char *name, unsigned int age, unsigned int course);

struct student {
    char name[50];
    unsigned int age;
    unsigned int course;
};

unsigned int student_counter = 0;

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    struct student *st[20];

    st[0] = addStudent("Руслан", 18, 1);
    student_counter += 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < student_counter; i++) {
        printf("%s \t %d курс \t  %d лет \n", st[i]->name, st[i]->course, st[i]->age);
    }

    return 0;
}

struct student *addStudent(char *name, unsigned int age, unsigned int course) {
    struct student *res_st = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    strcpy(res_st->name, name);
    res_st->age = age;
    res_st->course = course;

    return res_st;
}
```

а функцию addStudent у вас не получается создать потому что:

- в аргументах фунции после unsigned нужно написать тип данных int
- вы не возвращаете созданную вами структуру, она создается внутри функции и после ее завершения она пропадает
- в аргументах дублируется обьявление age

Comment: Проблема у автора вопроса была не в том, что он использовал не динамическую память, а в том, что он даже не пытался указать `struct student`, а не просто `struct` в возвращаемом типе, а в самой функции даже не пытался что-то возвращать. Вы просто сделали за него работу, так что ждите следующего вопроса такого же уровня непонимания азов языка. Вы же помогли не понять, а сдать... И, кстати, опущенный `int` при `unsigned` ошибкой в С не является.